# Inferring Memory Alignment

Tags: c, memory-management, portability

The following code is intended to infer the alignment of `double`.

My questions include:

1. Is there a better to do this? Either by refining the code or using an entirely different approach.
2. Under what (reasonable) circumstances could this not work?
3. Under what (plausible) circumstances could this not work? See below.
4. What is the actual or practical complete list of types I would need to do this with to determine universal alignment?

   I think it's `short`,`int`,`long`,`long long`,`float`,`double`, `long double`, `void*`.
   Specifically `char` can't be have a alignment constraint (or c-strings are broken!), `unsigned` can't be different from signed (or type-aliasing is broken).
   Is there any reason why `void*` can't stand in for all pointer alignments?

```
#include <stdio.h>

// *********************************************************************** //
//WARNING: Do not allow this translation unit to be compiled under the 
//#pragma pack directive or similar unless whole application is compiled the same way.
// *********************************************************************** //

typedef struct {
    char mWedge;//Wedges the member off alignment with the start of the struct.
    double mMember;//Member with type we're going to get alignment of.
} DoubleAligned;

const size_t getDoubleAlignment(void){
//A bit of pointer shennanigans to count the padding between mWedge & mMember.
//See text. 
    const DoubleAligned lSpecimen;
    const size_t lOffset= (char*)&(lSpecimen.mMember)-(char*)&(lSpecimen.mWedge);
    return lOffset;
}

int main(void) {
    printf("Alignment : %zu\n",getDoubleAlignment());
    return 0;
}
```

Expected output on platform where `double` has 4-byte alignment:

> Alignment : 4

Expected output on platform where `double` has no alignment (AKA 1-byte alignment:

> Alignment : 1

NB: If the compiler 'packs' structures by default and just 'takes the hit' on slicing and shuffling to get them into hardware alignment, I don't mind getting an output of 'Alignment : 1'. I'm interested in how the platform (programming environment presented to me) is aligned not trying to infer underlying hardware design.

**Reasoning**

The C specification (C99 to be specific) makes the following commitments:

1. `malloc(.)` returns a universally aligned address.
2. Structures can pad between members and at the end but specifically not the beginning.
3. Arrays of adjacent structures must be aligned in a way compatible with their members.
4. Members will be laid out in the order they are declared.

So the compiler has to place `mMember` in an aligned position after `mWedge` itself aligned to the start of `DoubleAligned`. The C specification doesn't further constrain why or how structures are padded but there appears to be no normal reason to pad them other than minimally to satisfy 2, 3 & 4 above.

Hence my question about 'plausible' circumstances. Formally the compiler can do what it likes including adding arbitrary space into structures (but not at the beginning) for reasons that have nothing to do with alignment - maybe debug info or overwrite detection. Does that actually happen?

I'm not entirely sure about `void*` standing in for all pointer types. `void*` must have the lowest-common-factor alignment of all the pointer types (not the types pointed to!).

Bonus Note:

On many platforms I can get away with:

```
const size_t getDoubleAlignment(void){
//A bit of pointer shennanigans to count the padding between mWedge & mMember.
//See text. 
    const DoubleAligned* lSpecimen=NULL;
    const size_t lOffset= (char*)&(lSpecimen->mMember)-(char*)&(lSpecimen->mWedge);
    return lOffset;
}
```

But I believe this is formally undefined because it performs arithmetic on `NULL`.

Final Note: **Why do you need to know?** (someone will ask) Suppose I need a portable alternative `malloc(.)` implementation that uses pre- and post- 'overhead' areas. I could implement it around the native `malloc(.)` but would need to know what "universal alignment" meant to comply with the C standard for `malloc(.)` to carve out a universally aligned return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Is there a better to do this (infer the alignment of `double`)?

Curious as to why `size_t` type is used.  The first choice should be `ptrdiff_t`.

> When two pointers are subtracted, ... and its type (a signed integer type) is `ptrdiff_t` defined in the `<stddef.h>` header.  C11dr §6.5.6 9

Since alignment is certainly something less than 127, *any* integer type will do for our purposes.  Could use `int`, `unsigned`, `size_t`.

The cast of `&(lSpecimen.mWedge)` is redundant other than to remove the `const`

My GCC 4.5.3 compiler says the `const` on the return type is ignored.

```
int getDoubleAlignment(void) {
  const DoubleAligned lSpecimen;
  const int lOffset = (char*)&(lSpecimen.mMember) - &(lSpecimen.mWedge);
  return lOffset;
}
```

---

2. Under what (reasonable) circumstances could this not work?  (Nothing to add)
3. Under what (plausible) circumstances could this not work? (Nothing to add)

---

4. What is the actual or practical complete list of types I would need to do this with to determine universal alignment?

Rather than use `double`, use `max_align_t` if available.  `max_align_t` is not in C99.

> "... `max_align_t` which is an object type whose alignment is as great as is supported by the implementation in all contexts ..."  C11dr §7.19 2

Otherwise instead of `double` use a union of all non-narrow types:

```
union {
  int i;
  long l;
  long long ll;
  float f;
  double d;
  long double ld;
  float _Complex fc;
  double _Complex dc;
  ptrdiff_t pd;
  // Suspect the below are the only 4(5) code may truly need
  long double _Complex ldc;
  void *p;
  void (*pf)();
  intmax_t im;
  // C11
  max_align_t ma;
} OneOfEach;
```

`void*` might be narrower than `void (*pf)()` so `void*` will not work for all pointers.

Comment: Thanks. I agree I should probably have used `ptrdiff_t`. I notice the `offsetof(.,.)` macro (C99) also returns `size_t`. It turns out I should have used that. I think there's a tendency to use `size_t` when (as here) the result is known to be non-negative. Though as you point out almost any type would do.
I agree, I made one unnecessary cast and shouldn't have thrown away `const`. I wasn't aware of `max_align_t` that's useful in trying to emulate `malloc(.)` properly. It's interesting that portability support for alignment has been weak for so long.

Answer (score 0):

My revised code is (for the relevant part):

```
#include <stddef.h> //Defines offsetof(.,.) 

#define alignment_of(type) offsetof(struct { char w;type v;},v)

const size_t getDoubleAlignment(void){
    return alignment_of(double);
}
```

I should have used the `offsetof(.,.)` macro.

See a discussion here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700114/portability-of-using-stddef-hs-offsetof-rather-than-rolling-your-own

**NOT RECOMMENDED**

If `offsetof(.,.)` isn't available then the most portable solution is (I believe):

```
const size_t getDoubleAlignment(void){
    const DoubleAligned lSpecimen;
    const size_t lOffset= (const char*)&(lSpecimen.mMember)-&(lSpecimen.mWedge);
    return lOffset;
}
```

I set aside discussions of `size_t` vs `ptrdiff_t` for compatibility with `offsetof(.,.)`.